# There is no natural isomorphism between torsion functor and identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the full subcategory of $\textbf{Ab}$ whose objects are finitely generated abelian groups. Let $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}$ be the functor sending $A\in\mathcal{C}$ to $A_{\text{tor}}\oplus A/A_{\text{tor}}$. I want to show there is not natural isomorphism $F\rightarrow\text{id}_{\mathcal{C}}$.

For the sake of contradiction, suppose there exists a natural isomorphism $u:F\rightarrow\text{id}_\mathcal{C}$. For each $A\in\textbf{Ab}$, let $v(A):=\iota_{A,2}\circ\pi_A$ where $\pi_A:A\rightarrow A/A_{\text{tor}}$ is the canonical surjection and $\iota_{A,2}:A/A_{\text{tor}}\rightarrow A_{\text{tor}}\oplus A/A_{\text{tor}}$ is the canonical injection. Clearly $v:\text{id}_{\mathcal{C}}\rightarrow F$ is a natural transformation. Thus we have $u\circ v:\text{id}_{\mathcal{C}}\rightarrow\text{id}_{\mathcal{C}}$ and so there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$u(A)\circ v(A)=n\cdot\text{id}_A$$
for all $A\in\mathcal{C}$. In fact $n=u(\mathbb{Z})(v(\mathbb{Z})(1))=u(\mathbb{Z})(0,\pi_{\mathbb{Z}}(1))$.

To get a contradiction, it's sufficient to show that necessarily $n=\pm1$. How to prove this?

**Edit:** Note that $A_{\text{tor}}$ is the torsion subgroup of the abelian group $A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a detailed solution of this in [E. Riehl's *Category Theory in Context*](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf) (Proposition $1.4.4$).

You are almost there. To finish the proof we consider the components of the constructed natural transformation at both $A=\mathbb Z$ and $A=\mathbb Z/2n\mathbb Z$. From the first case we get that $n\ne0$ while the second case implies that $n=0$ as the given component factors through the trivial group ($\mathbb Z/2n\mathbb Z$ is torsion). This completes the argument.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an argument tangential to but imho not the same as that in CTiC:

---

Let $\textbf{Ab}_{<\infty}$ be the ($\textbf{Ab}$-enriched) category of finitely generated Abelian groups and $\left|-\right|\colon \textbf{Ab}_{<\infty}\to \textbf{Ab}$ be its fully faithful inclusion into $\textbf{Ab}$. Denote by $$0\to \text{tors}\to\text{id}\to \text{cotors}\to 0$$ the evident short exact sequence of ($\textbf{Ab}$-enriched) torsion subgroup, identity, and quotient by torsion subgroup functors respectively in the ($\textbf{Ab}$-enriched) functor category $\textbf{Ab}_{<\infty}\to \textbf{Ab}_{<\infty}$.

By virtue of the exactness of $\left|-\right|$, it suffices to show that the SES $$0\to \left|\text{tors}\right|\to\left|-\right|\to \left|\text{cotors}\right|\to 0$$ does not split in the functor category $\textbf{Ab}_{<\infty}\to\textbf{Ab}$. (Where $\left|\text{tors}\right|:= \left|-\right|\circ\text{tors}$, $\left|\text{id}\right|=\left|-\right|$, etc..)

To that end, remark that $\left|-\right|$ is corepresented by $\mathbb{Z}$. It follows from the ($\textbf{Ab}$-enriched) Yoneda lemma that there is an isomorphism $$\left[\left|-\right|,\text{tors}\right]\ \simeq\ \text{tors}\left(\mathbb{Z}\right)\ \simeq\ 0\text{.}$$
As $\left|\text{tors}\right|$ is nonzero (there being objects of $\textbf{Ab}_{<\infty}$ on which it doesn't vanish), the inclusion $\left|\text{tors}\right|\to\left|-\right|$ admits no retraction, and thus the latter (and thus former) SES above does not split, as claimed. $\blacksquare$

---

Of course, if we wish to avoid speaking in terms of enrichment, we can just directly mimic the proof of the Yoneda lemma in the specific case at hand, which is what Riehl does when she computes $\left[\text{id},\text{id}\right]\simeq\mathbb{Z}$.

Also, note that we could have instead proceeded above by computing that $\left[\left|\text{cotors}\right|,\left|-\right|\right]\simeq 0$; this follows from the evident LES $$0\to\left[\left|\text{cotors}\right|,\left|-\right|\right]\to \underbrace{\left[\left|-\right|,\left|-\right|\right]}_{\simeq\ \mathbb{Z}\text{ by Yoneda}}\to \left[\left|\text{tors}\right|,\left|-\right|\right]$$ and that no multiple of $\left|-\right|$ vanishes torsion.

(In fact, by writing $\left|\text{tors}\right|$ as the filtered colimit of $\left[\mathbb{Z}/n,-\right]$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ as indexed by the poset ordered by divisibility, we compute—once more by the Yoneda lemma—the above morphism $\left[\left|-\right|,\left|-\right|\right]\to \left[\left|\text{tors}\right|,\left|-\right|\right]$ to be none other than the inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\to\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$.)